# Does an Indian citizen need a transit visa in Hong Kong when travelling to Australia?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, hkg

I am travelling to Australia via Hong Kong. I have a layover time of 16 hours in one of the trips. Please tell me if I need a visa if I stay in the airport and travel from one terminal to the other terminal.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   - Those who are in direct (Air to Air or Air to Sea) transit
>     if holding confirmed onward bookings, continuing their
>     journey within 48 hours and not leaving the transit lounge.

So if your trip is in a single booking, you do **not** Need a visa.